# How to format edit, update, delete buttons of gridview using bootstrap in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, bootstrap-4, webforms

Currently I have a gridview with edit, delete and update buttons enabled on a gridview in asp.net web form. Just wandering how to edit those buttons as by default they are designed to look as a simple hyperlink.

heres the gridview design code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-bordered" runat="server" 
  AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
  AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" DataKeyNames="Sr_No" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
  OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sr_No" HeaderText="Sr_No" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sr_No" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="From_Date" HeaderText="From_Date" SortExpression="From_Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="To_Date" HeaderText="To_Date" SortExpression="To_Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="No" HeaderText="No" SortExpression="No" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" SortExpression="Remarks" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

As seen in the above code, I cannot find the button lines in this design.
Thanks in advance.(I am just a beginner in .net dev)

Comment: Hello! Does this answer your question? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1276525/ASP-NET-Gridview-Editable-in-Web-Forms-using-Boots

Comment: Don't AutoGenerate the buttons then.  Create them using ItemTemplates and then using an <asp:Button> and adding a CSS styling for bootstrap like "btn btn-success"

Comment: JohnPete22 Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a TemplateField with a LinkButton that has the CommandNames `Edit`, `Delete`, `Cancel` and `Update` etc then you can style them.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="editRow" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```